# How to export matrix modified with matsplitter in R

Tags: r, matrix, output

I need to export a matrix from R to a *.txt file that has been split with the matsplitter function without loosing the format created, i.e. I need the data to be in subsets of three lines and five columns.

the matspliltter function:

```
matsplitter<-function(M, r, c) {
rg <- (row(M)-1)%/%r+1
cg <- (col(M)-1)%/%c+1
rci <- (rg-1)*max(cg) + cg
N <- prod(dim(M))/r/c
cv <- unlist(lapply(1:N, function(x) M[rci==x]))
dim(cv)<-c(r,c,N)
cv}
```

example matrix, splitting and output

```
B <- matrix(c(1:1380),ncol=5)

matsplitter(B,3,5)

write.table(B,file="outfile.txt",sep="\t", col.names = F, row.names = F)
```

The write.table will loose the splitting and make a file with only three rows. How can I retain the appearance of the output produced by matsplitter in the *.txt file?

and an example on what the result should look like when completed (the ", , 1" and so forth needs to be replaced by the character string:

"tstep" 0 "item" 1 "layer" 0

so the final output would look like this:

```
"tstep" 0 "item" 1 "layer" 0
1  277  553  829 1105
2  278  554  830 1106
3  279  555  831 1107

"tstep" 1 "item" 1 "layer" 0
4  280  556  832 1108
5  281  557  833 1109
6  282  558  834 1110

"tstep" 2 "item" 1 "layer" 0
7  283  559  835 1111
8  284  560  836 1112
9  285  561  837 1113
```

etc. with the "tstep" increasing with every new set of data.

Comment: Try `?capture.output` i.e. `capture.output(matsplitter(B,3,5), file='outfile.txt')` if you need to retain the appearance of the output

Comment: Thanks, this does produce something similar to what I need, I still need to drop the column and row names.

Comment: It would have been better if you showed a few lines of how you wanted the expected output.  Do you need the `, , 1`  that separates the array elements

Comment: Yes that would probably have clarified the question, I opted to construct an example with arbitrary data. I actually don't need the ", , 1" that separate the arrays, I will however in the next step (thought I'd just ask one question at a time) to replace the ", , 1" with another character string.

Comment: Have you tried the posted solution with `write.table`.  It may work with your specifications.  Also, after you create the `outfile.txt` with `capture.output`, you can remove the `column/row names` i.e. `write.table(gsub('\\[.*\\]', '', readLines('outfile.txt')), file='outfile.txt', row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)`  If you were working on linux, this could be solved with `awk`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly the goal is:

- tab delimited columns
- each row in a new line
- extra new line for each group

For example:

```
test <- matsplitter(B,3,5)

apply(test, 3, function(x){
  write.table(as.data.frame(x),file="outfile.txt",sep="\t", col.names = F, row.names = F, append = TRUE )
  cat("\n", file = "outfile.txt", append = TRUE, fill = F )
})
```

Comment: The above apply -application gives me an error "Error in if (d2 == 0L) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" ?

Comment: @eze I think `test <- matsplitter(B,3,5)`

Comment: @eze the input array must have 3 dimensions (as akrun said: `test` is here a result of the matsplitter)